# Left Outer Join in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, t-sql, left-join, predicate, sql-server-2014

We are currently upgrading to SQL Server 2014; I have a join that runs fine in SQL Server 2008 R2 but returns duplicates in SQL Server 2014.  The issue appears to be with the predicate `AND L2.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = RG.PERIOD_TO` for if I change it to anything but 4, I do not get the duplicates.  The query is returning those values in Accounting Period 4 twice. This query gets account balances for all the previous Accounting Periods so in this case it returns values for Accounting Periods 0, 1, 2 and 3 correctly but then duplicates the values from Period 4.

```
SELECT
  A.ACCOUNT,
  SUM(A.POSTED_TRAN_AMT),
  SUM(A.POSTED_BASE_AMT),
  SUM(A.POSTED_TOTAL_AMT)
FROM
  PS_LEDGER A 
  LEFT JOIN PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL B  
    ON B.SETID = 'LTSHR'                    
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_LEDGER L2 
    ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = L2.BUSINESS_UNIT
      AND A.LEDGER = L2.LEDGER
      AND A.ACCOUNT = L2.ACCOUNT                                    
      AND A.ALTACCT = L2.ALTACCT
      AND A.DEPTID = L2.DEPTID
      AND A.PROJECT_ID = L2.PROJECT_ID
      AND A.DATE_CODE = L2.DATE_CODE
      AND A.BOOK_CODE = L2.BOOK_CODE
      AND A.GL_ADJUST_TYPE = L2.GL_ADJUST_TYPE
      AND A.CURRENCY_CD = L2.CURRENCY_CD
      AND A.STATISTICS_CODE = L2.STATISTICS_CODE
      AND A.FISCAL_YEAR = L2.FISCAL_YEAR
      AND A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = L2.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD
      AND L2.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD = RG.PERIOD_TO
WHERE 
  A.BUSINESS_UNIT       = 'UK001'
  AND A.LEDGER          = 'LOCAL'
  AND A.FISCAL_YEAR     = 2015
  AND ( (A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD BETWEEN 1 and 4
         AND B.ACCOUNT_TYPE IN ('E','R') )
                OR
        (A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD BETWEEN 0 and  4
         AND B.ACCOUNT_TYPE IN ('A','L','Q') )   )
  AND A.STATISTICS_CODE = ' '
  AND A.ACCOUNT = '21101'
  AND A.CURRENCY_CD <> ' '
  AND A.CURRENCY_CD = 'GBP'
  AND B.SETID='LTSHR'
  AND B.ACCOUNT=A.ACCOUNT
  AND B.SETID = SETID
  AND B.EFFDT=(SELECT MAX(EFFDT) FROM PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL WHERE SETID='LTSHR'  AND  WHERE ACCOUNT=B.ACCOUNT AND EFFDT<='2015-01-31 00:00:00.000')
GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT
ORDER BY A.ACCOUNT
```

Comment: The first guess is that the data is different in the two databases you are testing.

Comment: And unfortunately a guess it will remain, without some DDL and DML for us to reproduce the scenario...

Comment: Note that by placing equality predicates in your `WHERE` clause for columns of table `B`, you have effectively converted your `LEFT JOIN` of that table into an inner join.  That's probably ok, though, because that join's condition does not rely on the left table at all, so it's really a cross join of a subset of the right-hand table.

Comment: What's `RG`?  There is no such table or alias named anywhere in the `FROM` clause, but you reference it in the join predicate.

Comment: That is not even valid syntax.  rg is not defined and you have  two where in the FROM PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL

Comment: Also, what's the meaning of this condition: `B.SETID = SETID`? Is the unqualifed `SETID` supposed to refer to a column of table `A`?

Comment: RG was a mistke in the SQL. I removed all other joins to reduce the possibilities. I just forgot to delete it.

Comment: yes; the unqualified SETID refers to PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL.  I did not write this code so any suggestions for improvement are very welcome.

Comment: If the unqualified `SETID` refers to `PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL` then `B.SETID = SETID` is equivalent to `B.SETID IS NOT NULL`, which is redundant with, and less selective than, `B.SETID = 'LTSHR'`.

Comment: I moved the predicate out of the where clause and  now return no rows.                                                                                                         SELECT SUM(A.POSTED_TRAN_AMT), SUM(A.POSTED_BASE_AMT), SUM(A.POSTED_TOTAL_AMT)
FROM  PS_LEDGER A 
LEFT JOIN PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL B  
  ON B.SETID = 'LTSHR'   
LEFT JOIN PS_RUN_GL_TRLBAL RG 
ON RG.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT              
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_LEDGER L2 
ON A.BUSINESS_UNIT = L2.BUSINESS_UNIT AND L2.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD =  RG.PERIOD_TO

Comment: If you remove a predicate `AND`ed into the `WHERE` clause without changing the data in the base tables, then the resulting query cannot return fewer rows than the original one did.  If you in fact did get fewer rows then either you changed the query more than that or your data changed.

Comment: Sorry I was incorrect; I get the same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm inclined to suspect that you have simplified your original query too much to reflect the real problem, but I'm going to answer the question as posed, in light of the comments on it to this point.

Since your query does not in fact select anything derived from table `L2`, nor do any other predicates rely on anything from that table, the only thing accomplished by (left) joining it is to duplicate rows of the pre-aggregation results where more than one satisfies the join condition for the same `L2` row.  That seems unlikely to be what you want, especially with that particular join being a *self* join, so I don't see any reason not to remove it altogether.  Dollars to doughnuts, that solves the duplication problem.

I'm also going to suggest removing the correlated subquery in the `WHERE` clause in favor of joining an inline view, since you already join the base table for the subquery anyway.  This particular inline view uses the window function version of `MAX()` instead of the aggregate function version.  Ideally, it would directly select only the rows with the target `EFFDT` values, but it cannot do so without being rather more complicated, which is exactly what I am trying to avoid.  The resulting query therefore filters `EFFDT` externally, as the original did, but without a correlated subquery.

I furthermore removed a few redundant predicates and rewrote one of the messier ones to a somewhat nicer equivalent.  And I reordered the predicates in a way that seems more logical to me.

Additionally, since you are filtering on a specific value of `A.ACCOUNT`, it is pointless (but not wrong) to `GROUP BY` or `ORDER_BY` that column.  Accordingly, I have removed those clauses to make the query simpler and clearer.

Here's what I came up with:

```
SELECT
  A.ACCOUNT,
  SUM(A.POSTED_TRAN_AMT),
  SUM(A.POSTED_BASE_AMT),
  SUM(A.POSTED_TOTAL_AMT)
FROM
  PS_LEDGER A 
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT
        *,
        MAX(EFFDT) OVER (PARTITION BY ACCOUNT) AS MAX_EFFDT
      FROM PS_GL_ACCOUNT_TBL 
      WHERE
        EFFDT <= '2015-01-31 00:00:00.000'
        AND SETID = 'LTSHR'
    ) B  
    ON B.ACCOUNT=A.ACCOUNT
WHERE 
  A.ACCOUNT = '21101'
  AND A.BUSINESS_UNIT   = 'UK001'
  AND A.LEDGER          = 'LOCAL'
  AND A.FISCAL_YEAR     = 2015
  AND A.CURRENCY_CD = 'GBP'
  AND A.STATISTICS_CODE = ' '
  AND B.EFFDT = B.MAX_EFFDT
  AND CASE
      WHEN B.ACCOUNT_TYPE IN ('E','R')
        THEN A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD BETWEEN 1 and 4
      WHEN B.ACCOUNT_TYPE IN ('A','L','Q')
        THEN A.ACCOUNTING_PERIOD BETWEEN 0 and 4
      ELSE 0
    END
```